# Проблема с паттернами

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, шаблоны-проектирования, table

Мне нужно установить цвета тем словам, которые были внесены как паттерны в таблице.
Проблема в том, что он просто не видит эти паттерны.
Что я делаю не так?

```
        const code =  document.querySelector('code');
        const example = `
        SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (100.23, 234, 42) AND name LIKE 'ivan';
        INSERT INTO groups (name, tags) VALUES ('Type 'A1,a, type'), ('group 42',group, 42')
        `;

        const patterns = {
            exp: /(SELECT|FROM)/gi,
        }
        for (let pattern in patterns) {
            let result = example.replace(pattern.exp, `<span/>${pattern.exp}</span>`);
            code.innerHTML = result;
        }
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, _что он просто не видит эти паттерны_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Вы не правильно вызываете функцию замены, так должно сработать

```
let result = example.replace(patterns[pattern], "<span>$1</span>");
```